# jQuery validate upload only, if file chosen

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using the jQuery validate plugin to validate my forms. For one form there should be an optional upload field. 
With the rule

```
  rules : {
        image_file : {
            accept: "image/*",
    }
```

it is automaticly required, also if the upload field is left empty.

Comment: That is impossible.  Without the `required` rule, the field is always optional.  So where is the rest of your relevant code?  Where is the relevant HTML markup?  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/agpwk0nv/

Answer (score 0):

```
rules : {
    image_file : {
        accept: "image/*",
    }
    ....
```

> it is automaticly required, also if the upload field is left empty.

That's **absolutely impossible** with the code you've shown us.

**DEMO:  [http://jsfiddle.net/agpwk0nv/1](http://jsfiddle.net/agpwk0nv/1/)**

---

It's most likely that you have the `required` attribute or class on your `input` without realizing it.

```
<input type="file" name="image_file" required="required" />
```

OR

```
<input type="file" name="image_file" class="required" />
```

If you want this to be "optional", then you'll need to remove `required`.